# Отладка библиотеки vcompd.lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp

Можно ли в Visual Studio отлаживать код библиотеки vcompd.lib, и если можно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любую библиотеку можно отлаживать, если она собрана в режиме отладки и Visaul Studio знает где лежат PDB файлы для библиотеки. Если у Вас именно такая библиотека и есть PDF файлы, Вы можете указать путь к ним в `Debug->Options->Symbols`.